# google-plus-ios-sdk 1.4.0 NSInvalidArgumentException at GPPService getPreviewForLinkAttachment

Tags: ios, google-plus

I'm working with the new google-plus-ios-sdk-1.4.0 (http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/10/ios-sdk-1.4.0.html).  I've followed the walkthrough at http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/10/google-ios-sdk-140-with-native-sharing.html, as well as the GooglePlusSample.xcodeproj within the SDK.

However, I keep getting this exception.  I've verified that I'm authed.  I've tried sharing simple text, url's, deep linking, and call-to-action, but I keep getting this exception below.

It's been less than a week since release, so nothing comes up on web searches.  Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
NSInvalidArgumentException "-[__NSCFString absoluteString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18168b00"  
 -[GPPService getPreviewForLinkAttachment:finished:] + 200, 
 -[GPPNativeShareComposeViewController loadPreviewForLink] + 366,   
 -[GPPNativeShareComposeViewController viewDidLoad] + 3048, 
 -[GPPNativeShareController openWithService:parameters:] + 940, 
 -[GPPNativeShareBuilderImpl open] + 322,   
 -[MBGooglePlusActivityProvider finishedWithAuth:error:] + 666, 
 __37-[GPPSignIn addCallDelegateCallback:]_block_invoke + 116,  
 -[GPPCallbackQueue fire] + 158,    
 __44-[GPPSignIn addFetchGooglePlusUserCallback:]_block_invoke_2 + 236, 
 -[GTLService handleParsedObjectForFetcher:] + 1136,    
 main + 116
2013-10-06 23:52:29.644 SampleApp[8755:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString absoluteString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18168b00'
```

Comment: Didi you use exception breakpoint? It may show us from where exactly this error is generating.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the code that is triggering this problem? I assume you're trying to share media of some kind?